# Android - SharedPreferences inside Adapter getView

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, adapter

I want to access SharedPref's inside my Adapter's getView. I get an error on MODE_PRIVATE = `MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable'

`SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);`

I fixed this by doing `mContext.MODE_PRIVATE`, but then I get an error on getPreferences = getPreferences(int) is undefined. How can I fix this?

Edit

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.griditemlayout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView gridtv;
        gridtv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.list.gridtext);


        SharedPreferences sP = ((Object) mContext).getPreferences(mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean b = sP.getBoolean(s[position], false);

        ...

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: can you post what you have inside getview method?

Comment: OKay I imported `import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE`, but I get an error on getPreferences = `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because you cast `Context` to the `Object` and `Object` doesn't have `getPreferences` method. Try using just context.

**UPD:** I was slightly wrong, try using `Activity` reference instead of `Context`

Comment: I changed it to `mContext.getPreferences...` and now I get this error `The method getPreferences(int) is undefined for the type Context`

Comment: I changed it to Activity, and i still get the same error: `The method getPreferences(int) is undefined for the type Tab01_FavAdapter`

Comment: so now you have something like this `Activity act = (Activity) mContext; act.getPreferences(int);` and it's not working?

Comment: All the error's go away now, but the app crashees on start, log cat:

    07-16 17:29:08.009: E/AndroidRuntime(8992): java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-16 17:29:08.009: E/AndroidRuntime(8992):  at com.pos.Tab01_FavAdapter.getView(Tab01_FavAdapter.java:49)

Comment: I have 3 lines:
`Activity context = null;`
`Activity act = (Activity) context;`
`SharedPreferences sP = act.getPreferences(1);`

Comment: Of course you would have null pointer exception, because you are trying to invoke method on null reference. What you really need is to pass real reference of your Activity inside adapter.

Comment: Please can you tell  me what lines I need to have exactly. Im a newbie :(

Comment: as I see you already have a Context from somewhere, I suppose it could be your Activity, so just try `SharedPreferences sP = ((Activity) mContext).getPreferences(mContext.MODE_PRIVATE);` instead of casting to `Object`

Comment: I got this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`

Comment: ok, than it's not an Activity. So just pass a reference to the Activity from the place where you create your adapter.

Comment: The reference to the Activity would be the Context right? This is passed to the Adapter through mContext. Is this not correct?

Comment: The reference to the Activity is of type Activity, and Activity is just a subclass of Context. So when passing Context it's unknown what concrete implementation of Context is passed in your case. So the answer to your question is yes, it is not correct. You need Activity reference.

Comment: Okay, so when I create a new instance of the adapter using `new Tab01_FavAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), StringArray)` after stringarray, I need a new parameter with Activity reference. How can I get the activity reference?

Comment: you just need to change `getActivity().getBaseContext()` to `getActivity()` and it should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33575/discussion-between-user1873880-and-extremis)

Answer (score 0):

You are casting your mContext Context into an Object, which does not contain the getPreferences() method. Once you fix the casting issue, import the Context reference and try using just getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).

Comment: This is what I have: `SharedPreferences sP = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` with the Context import and I get an error on `getPreferences` - the error is: `The method getPreferences(int) is undefined for the type Tab01_FavAdapter`

Comment: @user1873880 is actually on the right track with his answer. getPreferences() is a method of the Activity class, and you need to get a reference to the activity in which your adapter class is used. To get the Activity object, you probably need to include it as an argument in your Adapter's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First use Context instead of ((Object) mContext). Call your adapter by context
Use Integer Value 1 instead of `MODE_PRIVATE`